GSAP Draggable Card Deck Effect works on down drag but not up drag
I'm trying to create a similar effect as seen here: https://www.cieffemilano.it/en/
My attempt is below. I'm having a lot of trouble getting the swipe up to work. My approach was to take the first element in the list (cards[0]) and have it be "staged" below the active card (last card in the list, so the one that shows on top of all other). updateCards() seems to be updating the styles no problem on initial load, but doesn't apply the styles after that.
I'm using GSAP and the Draggable plugin.
Thank you!


gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);

const DECK_DEPTH = 5; // need at least 5 cards in the deck!
const ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
const DRAG_THRESHOLD = 50; // Adjust as needed

const cardsList = document.querySelector(".cards-list");

// Update cards properties without animation
function updateCards() {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    const depthIndex = cards.length - 1 - index; // 1 for the top card
    const scale = 1 - 0.1 * depthIndex;
    const brightness = 100 - 10 * depthIndex;
    const y = `${-3 * depthIndex}%`;
    const opacity = depthIndex < DECK_DEPTH ? 1 : 0;

    if (index === 0) {
      // "bottom" card gets its own little staging area below
      card.removeAttribute("style"); // Remove any previous inline styles
      gsap.set(card, {
        scale: 1,
        filter: "brightness(100%)",
        y: "100%",
        opacity: 1,
        zIndex: 1,
      });
    } else {
      // all other cards must stack
      gsap.set(card, {
        scale: scale,
        filter: `brightness(${brightness}%)`,
        y: y,
        opacity: opacity,
        zIndex: "auto",
      });
    }
  });
}

// Extracted dragging logic
function animateCards(draggedAmount) {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  const normalizedDrag = Math.min(
    Math.abs(draggedAmount) / cards[0].clientHeight,
    1
  );

  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    if (draggedAmount < 0) {
      if (index === 0) {
        return;
      }
    } else {
      if (index === cards.length - 1) {
        return;
      }
    }
    const depthIndex = cards.length - 1 - index;
    let scale, brightness, yPos;

    if (draggedAmount > 0) {
      // Dragging down (grow towards the viewer)
      scale = 1 - 0.1 * depthIndex + 0.1 * normalizedDrag;
      brightness = 100 - 10 * depthIndex + 10 * normalizedDrag;
      yPos = -3 * depthIndex + 3 * normalizedDrag;
    } else {
      // Dragging up (shrink away from the user)
      scale = 1 - 0.1 * depthIndex - 0.1 * normalizedDrag;
      brightness = 100 - 10 * depthIndex - 10 * normalizedDrag;
      yPos = -3 * depthIndex - 3 * normalizedDrag;
    }

    gsap.set(card, {
      scale: scale,
      filter: `brightness(${brightness}%)`,
      y: `${yPos}%`,
      opacity: () => {
        if (depthIndex < DECK_DEPTH) {
          return 1;
        } else if (depthIndex === DECK_DEPTH) {
          return normalizedDrag;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      },
    });
  });
}

// Initialize Draggable on the top card
function makeDraggables() {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card")
  const topCard = cards[cards.length - 1] 
  const stagedCard = cards[0]
  Draggable.create(topCard, {
    type: "y",
    zIndexBoost: false,
    onDragEnd: function () {
      const draggedAmount = this.endY - this.startY;

      if (Math.abs(draggedAmount) > DRAG_THRESHOLD) {
        if (draggedAmount > 0) {
          // Drag down
          const timeline = gsap.timeline({
            onComplete: () => {
              // Move the front card to the back of the deck
              cardsList.insertBefore(topCard, cardsList.firstElementChild);
              gsap.set(topCard, { y: `100%` });
              updateCards(); // Update the positions of the rest of the cards
              makeDraggables(); // Reinitialize Draggable on the new top card
            },
          });

          timeline.to(topCard, {
            y: "100%",
            duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
          });

          timeline.add(() => {
            const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
            cards.forEach((card, index) => {
              if (index === cards.length - 1) return;
              const depthIndex = cards.length - 1 - index;
              const scale = 1 - 0.1 * depthIndex + 0.1;
              const brightness = 100 - 10 * depthIndex + 10;
              const yPos = -3 * depthIndex + 3;

              gsap.to(card, {
                scale: scale,
                filter: `brightness(${brightness}%)`,
                y: `${yPos}%`,
                duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
              });
            });
          }, 0);
        } else {
          // Slide the front card up and move the rest of the deck
          const timeline = gsap.timeline({
            onComplete: () => {
              // Move the back card to the front of the deck
              gsap.set(stagedCard, { y: `100%` });
              cardsList.appendChild(stagedCard);
              updateCards(); // Update the positions of the rest of the cards
              makeDraggables(); // Reinitialize Draggable on the new top card
            },
          });

          timeline.to(stagedCard, {
            y: 0,
            zIndex: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
          });

          timeline.add(() => {
            const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

            cards.forEach((card, index) => {
              if (index !== 0) {
                const depthIndex = cards.length - 1 - index;
                const scale = 1 - 0.1 * depthIndex - 0.1;
                const brightness = 100 - 10 * depthIndex - 10;
                const yPos = -3 * depthIndex - 3;

                gsap.to(card, {
                  scale: scale,
                  filter: `brightness(${brightness}%)`,
                  y: `${yPos}%`,
                  duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
                });
              }
            });
          }, "<");
        }
      } else {
        // Reset position if threshold is not met
        gsap.to(this.target, {
          y: "0%",
          scale: 1,
          filter: "brightness(100%)",
          duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
        });
      }
    },
    onDrag: function () {
      const draggedAmount = this.endY - this.startY;
      const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

      if (draggedAmount < 0) {
        // Dragging up
        // gsap.set(this.target, {
        //   y: 0,
        // });

        // Extract the current transform value
        const currentTransform = stagedCard.style.transform;
        const translateYMatch = currentTransform.match(
          /translateY\((-?\d+)%\)/
        );
        let currentY = translateYMatch ? parseFloat(translateYMatch[1]) : 100;

        // Calculate the new Y position
        const newY = currentY + (draggedAmount / stagedCard.offsetHeight) * 100;

        gsap.set(stagedCard, {
          y: `${newY}%`,
        });
        animateCards(draggedAmount);
      } else {
        // Dragging down
        animateCards(draggedAmount);
      }
    },
  });
}

updateCards();
makeDraggables();
.layout {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}

.cards-list {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vmin;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: auto;
  right: 0%;
}

.body {
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
  background-color: #f1b8bb;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout">
    <div class="cards-list">
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
      <div class="card"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/666a24cf2bfa587ab46501de/66778bc4e640f671c48c20fe_Model%20portrait%20with%20tropical%20flowers%20(6).jpeg" class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>



